# remove space between 2nd box & 3rd box

Tags: html, css

in below image, you can see 3 boxes

[image]

There is some empty space between 2nd box & 3rd box, please help me to remove that space.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.qty-ct2 {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 34px;
}
```

**html**

```
<th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center" id ="cart2">
                        <?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>
```

Comment: Can you please post your html code, that will make it easier for us to help you :)

Comment: please visit [link1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/under-water-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) than

click on "Add to cart" button present in middle , than please visit [link2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/checkout/cart) , you can see boxes

Comment: That's not really helping me. You need to post your html code just as you did with your css code.

Comment: okay i will post html code in feew minutes

Comment: Please add a code snippet directly in your question using the "edit" link below the question.

Comment: you have a margin in the button. You can add this class `.decrease, .increase{margin:0}`  Only using the browser dev tools this issues are easy to solve

Comment: thanks for suport @blonfu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited **Just add

```
.increase {
         border-left: 0px solid #ccc !important;
         margin: 0px 0px !important;

 }
```

**!important** for if css is not applying because of existing code.

Comment: i tried your code, its displayed like this : http://prntscr.com/bgzkqi still some empty space left.

Comment: ya..you want fully stick to middle box border?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.increase {
    border-left: medium none;
    /* margin-right: 1px; */
    margin: 0;
    width: 34px;
}
```

Comment: i tried your code, its displayed like this : http://prntscr.com/bgzkqi still some empty space left.

Comment: you have more than one ´@media only screen´ so you need to insert this ´margin: 0; width: 34px;´ for all or just create a ´.increase´ if this values with ´!important´